# Python type hints: What does Callable followed by a TypeVar mean?

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, python-typing

I am trying to understand the type hint `Getter[T]` in the following piece of code:

#### Simplified example

```py
T = TypeVar('T')
Getter = Callable[[T, str], str]


class AbstractClass(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def extract(
        self,
        get_from_carrier: Getter[T],  #  <---- See here
        ...
    ) -> Context:
```

Help much appreciated since I have been breaking my head over this.

#### Original source code

The original source code is from the [OpenTelemetry project file "textmap.py"](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/blob/master/opentelemetry-api/src/opentelemetry/trace/propagation/textmap.py):

```py
import abc
import typing

from opentelemetry.context.context import Context

TextMapPropagatorT = typing.TypeVar("TextMapPropagatorT")

Setter = typing.Callable[[TextMapPropagatorT, str, str], None]
Getter = typing.Callable[[TextMapPropagatorT, str], typing.List[str]]


class TextMapPropagator(abc.ABC):
    """This class provides an interface that enables extracting and injecting
    context into headers of HTTP requests. 
    ...
    """

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def extract(
        self,
        get_from_carrier: Getter[TextMapPropagatorT],
        carrier: TextMapPropagatorT,
        context: typing.Optional[Context] = None,
    ) -> Context:
```

Comment: To me, that doesn't seem valid. Where did you get this code?

Comment: The intent, at least, seems to be that the second argument you pass to `get_from_elem` has the type expected for the first argument to `get`.

Comment: @chepner That would already be communicated with `C_` alone though wouldn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily; `get_from_elem(get: C_, elem: str)` wouldn't imply any connection between `get` and `elem`.

Comment: No, I meant `get_from_elem(get: _C, elem: _T)`. The extra subscript of `_C` seems to be trying to duplicate information already in `_C`.

Comment: If it helps, I was trying to understand this piece of code, I simplified the variable names when I posted the question: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/blob/master/opentelemetry-api/src/opentelemetry/trace/propagation/textmap.py#L38

Comment: @Carcigenicate Oh, that's possible. I deleted my answer and made it a comment because I'm too rusty in the actual use of such generics. I don't know if `mypy` would treat the two differently, or if either one matches my assumed intent.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it turns out it isn't super straightforward. `_C[_Z]` (where `_Z` is a `TypeVar`), evaluates to `typing.Callable[[~_Z, int], int]`, so it overwrites the first parameter. In the code you showed though, they're overwriting the parameter with the same type, so I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

A Callable followed by a type variable means that the callable is a generic function that takes one or more arguments of generic type `T`.

The type variable `T` is a parameter for any generic type.

The line:

```py
Getter = Callable[[T, str], str]
```

defines `Getter` as a type alias for a callable function whose arguments are of generic type `T` and string, and whose return type is string.

Therefore, the line:

```py
get_from_carrier: Getter[T]
```

defines an argument (`get_from_carrier`) that is a generic function. And the first argument of the generic function is of generic type `T`.

### Concrete Example

This can be better understood by looking at a concrete example. See `propagators.extract` below from ["instrumentation/opentelemetry-instrumentation-asgi/src/opentelemetry/instrumentation/asgi/**init**.py "](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/blob/master/instrumentation/opentelemetry-instrumentation-asgi/src/opentelemetry/instrumentation/asgi/__init__.py):

In the call `propagators.extract`, the function `get_header_from_scope` is a callable function whose first argument is of type `dict`, and this `dict` is serving as a `TextMapPropagatorT`.

```py
def get_header_from_scope(scope: dict, header_name: str) -> typing.List[str]:
    """Retrieve a HTTP header value from the ASGI scope.

    Returns:
        A list with a single string with the header value if it exists, else an empty list.
    """
    headers = scope.get("headers")
    return [
        value.decode("utf8")
        for (key, value) in headers
        if key.decode("utf8") == header_name
    ]


...


class OpenTelemetryMiddleware:
    """The ASGI application middleware.
    ...
    """

    ...

    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        """The ASGI application  ... """
        if scope["type"] not in ("http", "websocket"):
            return await self.app(scope, receive, send)

        token = context.attach(
            propagators.extract(get_header_from_scope, scope)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:** `_C[_T]` is a generic type alias that's equivalent to `Callable[[_T, int], int]`.

---

Here you're defining `_C` to be the type alias of `Callable[[_T, int], int]`. When an type alias contains a `TypeVar` (in this case, `_T`), it becomes a [generic type alias](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-type-aliases). You can use it the same way as you'd use built-in generic types like `List[T]` or `Dict[K, V]`, for example, `_C[str]` would be equivalent to `Callable[[str, int], int]`.

Then, type annotations of `get_from_elem` define it as a [generic function](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-functions). What this means is the the same type variable used within the entire function should be bound to the same class. To explain what this means, take a look at these function calls:

```py
_T = typing.TypeVar('_T')
_C = typing.Callable[[_T,int],int]

def get_from_elem(get: _C[_T], elem: _T):
    ...

def foo_str(a: str, b: int) -> int:
    # This function matches `_C[str]`, i.e. `Callable[[str, int], int]`
    ...

def foo_float(a: float, b: int) -> int:
    # This function matches `_C[float]`, i.e. `Callable[[float, int], int]`
    ...

def foo_generic(a: _T, b: int) -> int:
    # This function matches `_C[_T]`, it is also a generic function
    ...

_T2 = typing.TypeVar('_T2', str, bytes)

def foo_str_like(a: _T2, b: int) -> int:
    # A generic function with constraints: type of first argument must be `str` or `bytes`
    ...


get_from_elem(foo_str, "abc")      # Correct: `_T` is bound to `str`
get_from_elem(foo_float, 1.23)     # Correct: `_T` is bound to `float`

get_from_elem(foo_str, 1.23)       # Wrong: `_T` bound to two different types `str` and `float`
get_from_elem(foo_float, [1.23])   # Wrong: `_T` bound to two different types `float` and `List[float]`

get_from_elem(foo_generic, 1.45)   # Correct: `_T` is only bound to `float`
get_from_elem(foo_str_like, 1.45)  # Wrong: `_T` is only bound to `float`, but doesn't satisfy `foo_str_like` constraints
```

In the last two cases, the first argument is a generic function, which does not bind the type variable, so the type variable is only bound by the second argument. However, in the last case, `foo_str_like` has an additional constraint on its first argument type, and the bound type `float` does not satisfy that constraint, so it fails type checking.